# Bash Parallel processes in Netcat -c

Tags: bash, netcat

I am using netcat in a bash script as a pseudo server in order to run additional bash scripts from inputs entered. It's been something of an enjoyable side project, however I seem to have gotten stuck.

Essentially, The script and code runs perfectly, but output is not displayed until after the server finishes the process; as this can be a 40 hour process, it's not desirable to have the client with a loading screen and no prompt for the entire time.

Simply put, I would like to load a page based off the content to a point, ignoring the output of everything that follows. The code I have thus far is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $? -eq 0 ]; do
  nc -vlp 8080 -c'(
  r=read
  $r a b c
  z=$r
  while [ ${#z} -gt 2]; do
    $r z
  done
  f=`echo $b|sed "s/[^a-z0-9_.-]//gi"`
  o="HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
  c="Content"
  if [ -z "$f" ]; then
    f="index.html"
    echo "$o$c-Type: `file -ib $f`\n$c-Length: `stat  -c%s $f`"
    echo
    cat $f
  elif [ "$f"==Encrypt ]; then
    echo $o
    echo
    echo $(bash ~/webSupport.sh currentEncrypt "$b")
    bash ~/webSupport.sh pullVars "$b" &
  else
    echo -e "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\n\n404\n"
  fi
  )'
done
```

I've searched around, and cannot find any way to bypass it, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but it's hard to tell what the inputs and output are, can you expand on that? Looks interesting, good luck.

Comment: The inputs come from a web browser, with a being the protocol, b is the path.
Outputs are basic HTML, the script it calls to do encryption essentially says "Starting Encryption..." or "Encryption already in progress, please wait..." from an outbound echo. It's essentially calling `sleep 500000` in the pullVars line xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be enough to redirect the output streams (to `/dev/null` or a file if you need to keep it)

```
bash ~/webSupport.sh pullVars "$b" >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or close them:

```
bash ~/webSupport.sh pullVars "$b" >&- 2>&- &
```

Comment: That worked wonders; I had before assumed doing that within the external script itself would suffice, but now that I think about it, it makes perfect sense to need to be done here!
I do have to ask however, What precisely is the purpose of & in >&1 - I have never seen this symbol used in that manner.

Comment: `m>&n` means: redirect filedescriptor `'m'` to where filedescriptor `'n'` is currentyl pointing, execpt if `n` is `-`, then it means close `m`. so `>/dev/null 2>&1` means redirect stdout to /dev/null, then redirect stderr to where stdout points (which is /dev/null now), so it's just a shorter for of `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null`. You'll find a more complete explanation [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)